# wordress шаблон. определить пост это или не пост

Tags: wordpress, шаблоны, функции

Подскажите, как в шаблонах *wordpress*, в файле `header.php`, определить, открыта ли страница с постом или нет (например, страница категория или главная сайта).

Пробовал при помощи функции `get_the_ID()`. Думал, что она возвратит пустое значение, при открытии страницы категории или главной, но оказалось, что в таком случае, она возвращает `ID` самого верхнего поста на странице.

Comment: Ну так для поста можно свой [шаблон сделать](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), тогда если использует шаблон, то это пост ). Либо использовать [`is_singular( 'post' );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)

Answer (score 1):

```
is_singular( 'post' );
```

для страницы типа `пост`

Полный список условных тегов [в оригинале](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) и [на русском](http://wp-kama.ru/function-cat/uslovnyie-tegi)